# 2 lines LineGraph in dc-js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter, reductio

I might have missed something obvious but how do you plot a non-stacked line chart in `dc-js` ?

I have used the example jsFiddle as a base to try and add a second group to the lineChart definition but to no avail here : https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/pcn7mot5/

I defined a second group as :

```js
speedSumGroup2 = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.Speed * d.Run / 500;});
```

How do I plot it along with `speedSumGroup` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacked chart adds each line to the previous.

If the lines should be independent, the [series chart](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/series.html) is the way to go.